# Websocket Refuses Connection but receiving and emitting are still possible

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, nuxtjs

I have a Website Running under foo.domain.com and a websocket along with an express api under api.domain.com and whenever I'm trying to connect to it, i am receiving 400 as the response code, once the socket connected. However i am Receiving and Emitting Events successfully.
The Biggest Problem Being, that the Network tab is spammed by get and post requests every few seconds as a compensation for not being able to create the websocket relationship.

I Noticed the connection succeeds whenever the transport query is polling, but fails when its websocket.

This is My first Time Working With Websockets, so please bear with me.

Socket.io Version: 2.3.0

Express Version: 4.17.1

My Socket Script Running on my api

```
var listener = app.listen(6606, function () {
   console.log(`API listening on port ${listener.address().port}`)
});
let io = require('socket.io')(listener);

io.on('connection', socket => {
 console.log("Connected");
 var test = "Welcome";
 setTimeout(() => {
   socket.emit('test', test)
 }, 5000);
 socket.on('received', data => {
   console.log(data)
 })
})
```

And This the One Being Used inside my Nuxt.js Application

```
mounted() {
  this.websocket = socket("https://api.domain.com");
  this.websocket.on('test', data => {
    this.websocket.emit('received', {message: "Connected"})
  })
},
```

Console Output of my Websocket:

[image: Websocket Output]

Network Analysis from the Site:
[image: Network Analysis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After A Lot, I Mean a Ton of Research, i Figured Out that it was a Problem with my Apache2 Config.

I Had my API Running under The Port 6606.

Problem Being Apache didn't want to Upgrade my WebSocket Request and instead just threw an error.

If You have the Same Problem **Remember to Change every mention of 6606 to The Port Your Websocket Runs on**

Basically I had to Add:

```
  RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
   RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:6606%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

My Complete Apache Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName api.domain.com
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:6606/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6606/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName api.domain.com
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:6606/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6606/
  SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/chain.pem
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:6606%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</VirtualHost>
```